# Create 1 file and use a library (like python)

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm learning clojure and I'd like to use it for some simple things, like I do with python.

For example I'd like to whip up a .clj file in some directory full of CSV file and munge them around a little with some CSV library, without making a whole project out of it.

In python I'd make a .py file and just `import csv` at the top. Can I do that in clojure?

If not, what's the simplest way to do a little script like that?

So far everything I've found has said that I need a new lein project to do anything with libraries like that.

Comment: Since you are learning clojure why not write a csv libary yourself?

Comment: That was just an example, I'm just wondering if I can spin up a quick clojure script like I do with python. Typically what I want to do has 2 or 3 libraries associated with it.

Comment: It does sound like clojure ships with a pretty robust standard lib, and the java standard libs. So that might be good enough for my needs

Comment: Manual management of the Java classpath is tedious. I don’t recommend it. Use Leiningen: `lein new app throwaway`, add dependencies to `project.clj`, write some code, run with `lein run`.

Comment: Take a look at [lein-exec](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-exec), which lets you create clojure scripts.

Answer (score 4):

#### Use `boot` build tool

You can use [`boot`](http://boot-clj.com/) for that purpose. It is a build tool which allows you to write [standalone scripts](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki/Scripts) that execute your tasks (so it doesn't have to contain all the project structure). In the script you can specify all the dependencies you need, use other tasks or define yours. Just install `boot` and write a script.

For example to create a small script to read a CSV file provided on the command line you could write a following (e.g. `read-csv.boot`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env boot

(set-env! :dependencies '[[org.clojure/data.csv "0.1.3"]])

(require '[boot.cli :refer [defclifn]]
         '[clojure.data.csv :as csv]
         '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(defclifn -main
  [f file FILE str "input CSV file"]
  (println "Reading" file)
  (with-open [in-file (io/reader file)]
    (->> in-file
      (csv/read-csv)
      (println))))
```

Make it executable:

```
$ chmod +x read-csv.boot
```

And use it:

```
$ ./read-csv.boot -f input.csv
Reading input.csv
([1 2 3])
```

#### Comparison to `python`

In Clojure (and Java) dependency management is a bit different than in Python. In Python libraries are installed in the system as global packages and many of them are installed by default. You also have tools like `pip` that allow you to install additional packages globally. Clojure and Java usually use Maven dependencies in your projects (and don't install them and make available globally) which requires tools like build tools (e.g. `maven`, `ivy`, `lein` or `boot`) to setup your application classpath.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`inlein`](https://github.com/hyPiRion/inlein), which seems to be pretty neat:

```
#!/usr/bin/env inlein

'{:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [clojure-csv/clojure-csv "2.0.1"]]}

(require '[clojure-csv.core :as csv])

(println "Reading: " (first *command-line-args*))

(-> *command-line-args*
    first
    slurp
    csv/parse-csv
    println)

(System/exit 0)
```

Also it's startup time is impressive due to starting of background daemon.